# HTTP Error 400 when large size (1MB) post with FireFox + IIS + https + Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, firefox, iis

## Question

I get "HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid." error when I do a large size (1MB) post in an application created with ASP.NET Core.

This problem only occurs with Firefox, and only when https is enabled and Windows authentication is used.

I would like to know how to solve this size limitation.

## Occurrence condition

- FireFox
- IIS (with ASP.NET Core application)
- https
- Windows Authentication
- Large size (1MB) post

## What I have checked

### Code for verification

#### Form.cs

```cs
public class Form
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller.cs

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(int? size)
    {
        return View(new Form { Value = new string('X', size ?? 1024 * 1024) });
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Form form)
    {
        return View(form);
    }
}
```

#### Index.cshtml

```razor
@model WebApplication.Models.Form
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div>@Model.Value.Length</div>

<form method="post" asp-antiforgery="false">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Value"/>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

#### Startup.cs

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

### Browser Differences

- Chome 87.0
- IE 11
- FireFox 60.8 ESR
- FireFox 84.0.2

### protocols and authentication firrerence

- FireFox 84.0.2 + https + Anonymous Authentication
- FireFox 84.0.2 + http + Windows Authentication  (HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.)

### Size boundaries

- 1048569
- 1048570

"Value=" length 6 + 1048570 = 1MB.

## Unidentified points

- Error 400 is server error, but that there are differences between browsers.
- The error message is "The request verb is invalid", which means the "verb" is wrong.
- Server header is "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0", is it an error in http.sys and not IIS?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: I found this bug report.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1676331
The question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I conducted a test and found that this problem does exist.

I found in the IIS log that this error is actually not a 400 error but a 401 error. It also means that there is a problem with the verification between the browser and the server.

You can also use FRT in IIS to catch this error:

[image]

[image]

Below is the error log captured using FRT:

[image]

We can see that there is an error of 401.2 in IIS. In essence, 401.2 is usually not an "error". This is the challenge of authentication. Your browser cannot properly respond to the challenge.